# Attaching more than one Server to a Tape Library

Tags: dell-poweredge, sas, tape, scsi

We are running multiple Dell PowerEdge's and want to connect them to a Dell TL1000 Tape Library.

For my understanding, what we need is HBA cards for each Server to get the SAS connection.

I ran into the problem, that the TL1000 provides only one SAS port. How can all Servers use the Tape Library? I thought of daisychaining the SAS cable thru each HBA and then to the TL, is this correct?

Comment: I don't think this is really possible like this. Maybe the logical part on the SAS level could be handled with a SAS switch, but then you run into concurrency issues and other problem. The normal approach: Have only the backup server talking to the library and run backup clients  on the servers that talk to the backup server.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to run the backup server as a virtual machine? Or does it need to be dedicated?

Comment: Depends on your virt software, but if you can pass through the SCSI device, it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't do this at the SAS level, but at the software level. Most backup software supports storing data remotely; what you want is to do something like:

- Have a backup server that's connected to your tape library
- On that backup server, run some software that will schedule backups and write the data to tape
- On each server that needs to be backed up, run an agent that will send the to-be-backed-up data to the backup server.

SAS multi-host communication like that doesn't work very well, and also isn't necessary.

As for an example of a particular piece of software, I have had good experiences running backups to a [bacula](https://bacula.org) server, as well as its fork, [BareOS](https://www.bareos.org). Both support backing up Windows as well as Unix systems, although the backup server itself needs to run some form of Unix.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly second "SAS is not meant for multi-host communication like that." because that's precisely what SCSI and SAS are actually about - multi-initiator setup *should* be no problem. In practice however, many devices, HBAs and especially drivers and software *can't* handle situations like that correctly and I wouldn't set it up either.

Comment: Fair enough, updated that comment.